# How to revert back to old local changes in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, project

I did check out a project from server in eclipse. I made some changes in local machine. Accidentally, I replaced the project from latest from head. Now all my local changes are lost. Where can I find them ?

I checked local history but that only shows me file that were newly created.

Comment: please specify if you're using git, svn or whatever..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select individual files and on the right click menu use 'Replace With > Local History' (or 'Compare With > Local History').